# Flash FLV video import to timeline quality setting?

Tags: flash, flv, timeline

I'm trying to import a small .flv video to my flash file but I can't seen to find the setting to increase the import quality to 100%.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, you set up the import quality in MediaEncoder, or whatever software created the FLV.  Can you describe a bit more how you are loading the FLV, what version of Flash IDE you are using?  Is this FLV loading at runtime, or is it in the FLA file itself?